# Unable to find xml node wix spath

Tags: xml, wix, wix3.11

```
I am trying to update the web.config file while the installation process using the wix toolset 3.11. I am getting the error that xml node is not found while running the installer. I have tried this with xmlfile as well with xmlconfig with no success. Please help me in resolving this.
```

"Failed to find node: //configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='mydb"] in wb.config xml file."

Below is the xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MYNAME" connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=SOMEDB;Data Source=SOMEHOST"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Below is my code 

     <Component Id="cmpWebConfig" Guid="635F6999-89B4-42FF-89AC-9E2A710B42F8">
        <File Id="WEBCONFIG" Source="Web.Config" Name="Web.Config" KeyPath="yes"/>
        <!--<util:XmlConfig Id="setConnString" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]Web.config" Action="create" On="install" Node="value" Name="connectionString" Value="Data Source=[DB_INSTANCE]; Initial Catalog=Customers;Integrated Security=SSPI" ElementPath="//configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='mydb'[\]]" Sequence="1" />-->
        <util:XmlFile Id="ModifyConnectionString"
 Action="setValue"
 Permanent="yes"
 ElementPath="//configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='MYNAME'[\]]"
 Name="connectionString"
 File="[#WEBCONFIG]"
 Value="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=mydb;Data Source=[SQLHOST]"
 SelectionLanguage="XPath"
 Sequence="1" />
      </Component>
```

Comment: There is no <add name='mydb'> in your xml file.

Comment: after updating the value also i am same error that node does not exists  when the installer runs.

Answer (score 0):

This will you to solve your problem.

Remove extra slash before elementpath.

just copy and paste this and change the values

```
<util:XmlFile Id="ModifyConnectionString"
                     Action="setValue"
                     Permanent="yes"
                     ElementPath="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='MigratorDB'[\]]"
                     Name="connectionString"
                     File="[INSTALLFOLDER]web.config"
                     Value='Data Source=[DB_SERVER]; Initial Catalog=[DB_DATABASE]; User Id=[MMDB_USER]; Password=[MMDB_PASSWORD];'
                     SelectionLanguage="XSLPattern"
                     Sequence="1" />
```